# How to use Helvetica Neue in a beamer template on Overleaf?

Tags: beamer, fonts, helvetica

I'm trying to use Helvetica Neue (or any look-alike) as the only font in my presentation (title, normal text, items, section titles, and everything else), but I'm facing some issues.

When I use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\helveticalike{TeX Gyre Heros}

\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,family=\helveticalike}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section example}
    \begin{frame}{Frame title example}
        Some regular text
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I can apply the font singly with \setbeamerfont, e.g.:

```
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,family=\helveticalike}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries,family=\helveticalike}
...
\setbeamerfont{...}{series=\bfseries,family=\helveticalike}
```

But how can I apply it in the entire presentation (all text) without having to singly specify each element with \setbeamerfont?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Whilst someone may be able to answer with this info, it is best practice on this site to include a small example that can compile i.e. begin with your `\documentclass{beamer}` and end with `\end{document}`. This is important as people like to test solutions before posting them as answers if they're not quite confident with all of TeX and want to trial solutions. Could you edit your question to include a small example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the sans font, this should change (more or less) everything:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section example}
    \begin{frame}{Frame title example}
        Some regular text
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked just fine!
Tanks

Comment: @gabriel You're welcome!